# How to detect if a database structure changed? (not content!)

Tags: php, mysql

In my `php` script I want to check if a structure of database table has changed. The `DESCRIBE TABLE` wont provide enough informations, because it ignores the foreign keys. The `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is too much, because auto incremental value also appears here.

Comment: Look at the `information_schema.*`  tables. I think some combination of it's data will probably work well (columns, table_constraints  & triggers perhaps).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The SHOW CREATE TABLE is too much, because auto incremental value
>   also appears here.

Just filter out the auto incremental value with a regexp.

```
preg_replace('/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]+ /', ' ', $sql);
```

Comment: if you could include that regexp function please

Comment: Nice. (minor drawback is that it will show false negative if an index or a foreign key has been dropped and recreated with different name)

Comment: good point! depends on what you want to detect.. you could filter out that as well